# Smooth effect CSS animation for hover out

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to get a smooth "hover out" animation when you stop hovering the object. The font-awesome icon is rotating when you hover the whole button.

I'm using it:

```
@keyframes roll {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

.p-navEl a:first-child:hover::before {
    animation: roll .5s linear infinite;
}
```

HTML for the first button of the nav bar

```
<ul class="p-nav-list js-offCanvasNavSource">
  <li>
    <div class="p-navEl is-selected" data-has-children="true">
      <a href="#" class="p-navEl-link p-navEl-link--splitMenu " data-nav-id="forums">Forums</a>
      <a data-xf-key="1" data-xf-click="menu" data-menu-pos-ref="< .p-navEl" data-arrow-pos-ref="< .p-navEl" class="p-navEl-splitTrigger" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="Basculer en mode étendu" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"></a>
      <div class="menu menu--structural" data-menu="menu" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="menu-content">
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth0 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="newPosts">Nouveaux messages</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth0 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="findThreads">Trouver des discussions</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth1 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="yourThreads">Vos discussions</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth1 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="contributedThreads">Discussions avec vos messages</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth1 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="unansweredThreads">Discussions sans réponse</a>
          <hr class="menu-separator">
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth0 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="watched">Suivies</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth1 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="watchedThreads">Discussions suivies</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth1 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="watchedForums">Forums suivis</a>
          <hr class="menu-separator">
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth0 js-offCanvasCopy " data-nav-id="searchForums">Rechercher dans les forums</a>
          <a href="#" class="menu-linkRow u-indentDepth0 js-offCanvasCopy " data-xf-click="overlay" data-nav-id="markForumsRead">Marquer les forums comme lus</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

PREVIEW

*The bubble before "FORUMS" is rotating when you hover it. But I want the animation smooth when you stop hovering it*

[image: Preview]

but when you don't hover the link anymore, the animation is brutaly stopped.

Any idea?

**I can't share the original CSS since it's a userscript for a public/private website I'm not the owner!**

Comment: Try `animation-fill-mode: both;`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? Most won't have much time and it is better to just fix it and show than work on a fiddle from scratch.

Comment: can you please share html too ?

Comment: @Mr_Green Unfortunatly I can't... This is a usercss (my own CSS for a wesbite I use) I can't link the whole CSS that is actualy on the website.
I've edited my question with more details... Hope it will help to understand

Answer (score 0):

Please do try transitions like below and let me know [fiddle](https://codepen.io/naveensfiddle/pen/NmRYQr)!.

HTML

```
<body bgcolor="#333">
  <div class="display-center">
     <span>Rotate</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Css

```
.display-center{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
span {
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
    transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
span:hover {
  transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.70s;
  -moz-transition: 0.70s;
  -ms-transition: 0.70s;
  -o-transition: 0.70s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: All those prefixes are not needed. All modern browsers, IE 10 / 11 included, support the [standard `transition`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) and [standard `transform`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). Note: for IE, `ms-transition` has never existed as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've edited my question with HTML and some explanations why I can't share the actual CSS. I understand I have to put the transition on the not hover element but I don't use a transition in my code and it's a rotateY

Comment: Is there any precise reason for not using transitions @Pierrou